# No sé como imprimir en consola en Javascript, no encuentro el error

Tags: javascript, console

No sé por qué no aparece el resultado esperado en la consola.

Gracias.

```js
var brian = {  
    nombre: "brian",  
    edad: 52,  
    raza: "beagle",  
    ladrido: function() {  
        console.log("guau guau");  
    }  
}  
brian.ladrido;
```

Comment: Estás en [es.so]. Es innecesario que escribas en inglés :)

Answer (score 8):

Porque no estás llamando a la función **ladrido**.

```js
var brian = {
    nombre: "brian",
    edad: 52,
    raza: "beagle",
    ladrido: function() {
        console.log("guau guau");
    }
}
brian.ladrido(); // los paréntesis y listo
// guau guau
```

Answer (score 1):

Recuerda siempre hacer diferencia entre propiedades y/o métodos. Para trabajar propiedades de un objeto basta con nombreObjeto.propiedad, pero llamar un método o una función no olvides agregar los () al final del nombre de este.